# Integrating qdelaunay and qvoronoi function of qhull in c++

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, delaunay, voronoi, qhull

I know basics of visual studio and c++, but I am not an advanced user or programmer. What I want to do is to perform delaunay triangulation and generate voronoi grids using qhull library (using visual studio c++ in windows). I have no problem with preparing necessary data for calculation. My questions are:

1. What is the minimum necessary files to be included from qhull? (from what publicly free, the qhull is very powerful and contains a huge amount of files)
2. How can I easily perform the delaunay triangulation and generate voronoi grids? (like in delaunayn.m file of Matlab it calls " t = qhullmx(x', 'd ', opt); " then get the delaunay triangulation. )

Thank you so much for sharing your experience!

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is the C++ example in the `qhull`'s GitHub repository: https://github.com/qhull/qhull/tree/master/src/user_eg3